# How to check if a character is upper-case in Python?

Tags: python, string

I have a string like this

```
>>> x="Alpha_beta_Gamma"
>>> words = [y for y in x.split('_')]
>>> words
['Alpha', 'beta', 'Gamma']
```

I want output saying X is non conformant as the the second element of the list words starts with a lower case and if the string `x = "Alpha_Beta_Gamma"` then it should print string is conformant

Comment: What about an x="Alpha_BEta_Gamma"?

Comment: Good catch Alpha_BEta_Gamma is inavlid as it should be  Alpha_Beta_Gamma

Comment: @cris: it's completely irrelevant to the question and it certainly does not deserve py3k tag.

Comment: @SilentGhost: You're right when you say that the py3k tag is irrelevant to the main problem, but I added it because of her problems with `print`.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Maybe you want [`str.istitle`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.istitle)

```
>>> help(str.istitle)
Help on method_descriptor:

istitle(...)
    S.istitle() -> bool

    Return True if S is a titlecased string and there is at least one
    character in S, i.e. uppercase characters may only follow uncased
    characters and lowercase characters only cased ones. Return False
    otherwise.

>>> "Alpha_beta_Gamma".istitle()
False
>>> "Alpha_Beta_Gamma".istitle()
True
>>> "Alpha_Beta_GAmma".istitle()
False
```

Comment: Well hmm i have to mark right all though all the answers here were correct based on the original requirement i had given.

Comment: Well hmm i have to mark your answer as right allthough all the answers here were correct based on the original requirement i had given.

Answer (score 85):

To test that all words start with an upper case use this:

```
print all(word[0].isupper() for word in words)
```

Comment: >>> x="Alpha_beta_Gamma"
>>> words = [y for y in x.split('_')]
>>> print all(word[0].isupper() for word in words)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print all(word[0].isupper() for word in words)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @lisa: You have a really old Python version (<2.4). Write `print all([word[0].isupper() for word in words])` instead.

Comment: @lisa: in Python3 use `print(all...)` because `print` is a function, not a statement.

Comment: @THC4K: by the way old versions of Python didn't have `all()`. It is or was in a library provided by Google.

Comment: @Cristian Ciupitu: Ah you are right, in Python3 it fails with a Syntax Error too. I just guessed the problem was the lack of generator expressions.

Comment: Cristian well your answer by the way is brilliant to my original question

Answer (score 5):

```
x="Alpha_beta_Gamma"
is_uppercase_letter = True in map(lambda l: l.isupper(), x)
print is_uppercase_letter
>>>>True
```

So you can write it in 1 string

Comment: I think you got it backwards -- OP seems to want it to print true if and only if the first letter (and no other) of each word is uppercase, and with yours, it prints true even if the conditions aren't met.

Comment: Also, that's weird python, looks more like java than py... A list comprehension would be far more pythonic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
^[A-Z][a-z]*(?:_[A-Z][a-z]*)*$
```

Sample code:

```
import re

strings = ["Alpha_beta_Gamma", "Alpha_Beta_Gamma"]
pattern = r'^[A-Z][a-z]*(?:_[A-Z][a-z]*)*$'

for s in strings:
    if re.match(pattern, s):
        print s + " conforms"
    else:
        print s + " doesn't conform"
```

As seen on [codepad](http://codepad.org/lpuqkXtd)

Comment: +1 but it might fail for non-English characters, e.g. "Ălălalt".

Answer (score 2):

```
words = x.split("_")
for word in words:
    if word[0] == word[0].upper() and word[1:] == word[1:].lower():
        print word, "is conformant"
    else:
        print word, "is non conformant"
```

Comment: A part of the code is inefficient. You can replace it with `word[0].isupper()`.

Comment: And the other part with `word[1:].islower()`

Comment: @lisa: print is a function in Python 3.  Please don't literally type the code here without *thinking* first and changing Python 2 things (like print statement) to Python 3 things like a print function.  Also please don't say "giving me **an** error".  Please provide the **specific** error.

Comment: @S.Lott Thanks for guiding me so whats the expected norm of posting a error here are the specific errors posted in the comment section

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
def is_valid(string):
    words = string.split('_')
    for word in words:
        if not word.istitle():
            return False, word
    return True, words
x="Alpha_beta_Gamma"
assert is_valid(x)==(False,'beta')
x="Alpha_Beta_Gamma"
assert is_valid(x)==(True,['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma'])
```

This way you know if is valid and what word is wrong

Answer (score -1):

Use list(str) to break into chars then import string and use string.ascii_uppercase to compare against.

Check the string module:
http://docs.python.org/library/string.html