# How to format my string

Tags: python

```
def main():
    print('Please enter a sentence without spaces and each word has ' + \
          'a capital letter.')
    sentence = input('Enter your sentence: ')

    for ch in sentence:
        if ch.isupper():
            capital = ch
            sentence = sentence.replace(capital, ' ' + capital)


main()
```

Ex: sentence = 'ExampleSentenceGoesHere'

I need this to print as: Example sentence goes here

as of right now, it prints as:   Example Sentence Goes Here (with space at the beginning)

Comment: "Formatting your code" generally means changing the format of the _source code_ for a program. You're asking about how to format a string.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What does not work about the code you just posted?

Comment: What exactly is being asked here? You need to be much clearer. *Example sentence... prints as: *: include in the question us that actual print command and its output, and use ^^ underneath to highlight where the unwanted space is.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the string character by character and replace every upper case letter with a space and appropriate lower case letter:

```
>>> s = 'ExampleSentenceGoesHere'
>>> "".join(' ' + i.lower() if i.isupper() else i for i in s).strip().capitalize()
'Example sentence goes here'
```

Note that check if the string is in upper case is done by [isupper()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper). Calling [strip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) and [capitalize()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize) just helps to deal with the first letter.

Also see relevant threads:

- [Elegant Python function to convert CamelCase to snake_case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175208/elegant-python-function-to-convert-camelcase-to-camel-case)
- [How to check if a character is upper-case in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668964/how-to-check-if-a-character-is-upper-case-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the each uppercase letter to a lowercase one using `capital.lower()`. You should also ignore the first letter of the sentence so it stays capitalised and doesn't have a space first. You can do this using a flag as such:

```
is_first_letter = True
for ch in sentence:
    if is_first_letter:
        is_first_letter = False
        continue
    if ch.isupper():
        capital = ch
        sentence = sentence.replace(capital, ' ' + capital.lower())
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use `re` and `re.split("[A-Z]", text)` but I'm assuming you can't do that because this looks like homework. How about:

```
def main():
    text = input(">>")
    newtext = ""
    for character in text:
        if character.isupper():
            ch = " " + character.lower()
        else:
            ch = character
        newtext += ch
    text = text[0]+newtext[2:]
```

You could also do:

```
transdict = {letter:" "+letter.lower() for letter in 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'}
transtable = str.maketrans(transdict)
text.translate(transtable).strip().capitalize()
```

But again I think that's outside the scope of the assignment