# Difference between [y for y in x.split('_')] and x.split('_')

Tags: python, string, list, split

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3668964/1937994) and one thing in the original code bugs me:

```
>>> x="Alpha_beta_Gamma"
>>> words = [y for y in x.split('_')]
```

What's the point of doing this: `[y for y in x.split('_')]`? `split` already returns a list and items aren't manipulated in this list comprehension. Am I missing something?

Comment: Unless you like typing and pointless overhead there is no point

Comment: @Padraic I used to love typing and pointless overhead, but then I stopped using Java. :)

Comment: Some people are so enamored with ```xxx``` comprehensions that they will use them whenever they can.

Answer (score 8):

You're correct; there's no point in doing that. However, it's often seen in combination with some kind of filter or other structure, such as `[y for y in x.split('_') if y.isalpha()]`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in result but using list comprehension in this case in not a good way and in redundant!

```
>>> x="Alpha_beta_Gamma"
>>> [y for y in x.split('_')]
['Alpha', 'beta', 'Gamma']
>>> x.split('_')
['Alpha', 'beta', 'Gamma']
```